# Rolling calculation across a column - array-wise

Tags: python, pandas, finance, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to get a rolling n-day annualized equity return volatility but am having trouble implementing it. Basically, I would want to see in the last row (index 10) an implementation of sorts that does `np.std(df["log returns“]*np.sqrt(252)` for a rolling n-day window (e.g. index 6-10 for a 5-day window). If there aren't n values left, leave empty/fill with np.nan.

| Index | log returns | annualized volatility |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.01 |  |
| 1 | -0.005 |  |
| 2 | 0.021 |  |
| 3 | 0.01 |  |
| 4 | -0.01 |  |
| 5 | 0.02 |  |
| 6 | 0.012 |  |
| 7 | 0.022 |  |
| 8 | -0.001 |  |
| 9 | -0.01 |  |
| 10 | 0.01 |  |

I thought about doing this with a while loop, but since I'm working with a lot of data I thought an array-wise operation may be smarter. Unfortunately I can't come up with one for the life of me.

Comment: Does `np.sqrt(252)*df["log returns"].rolling(5).std()` do the job where `n = 5`?

Comment: This is spot on. Thanks a lot. I would have written 20 lines of code to get this result. Much appreciated.